# Selenium webdriver: IE crashes with "Command line server for the IE driver has stopped working"

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, webdriver

When attempting to run Selenium Webdriver tests with IE, the browser will launch but immediately crash with the error "Command line server for the IE driver has stopped working".

- The scripts where IE fails run just fine in Chrome and Firefox.
- Windows 10 IE 11.15.16299.0
- Python 3.6.3 (tried with Python 2.7.14)
- 32-bit IEDriverServer.exe version 3.5.0.0
- I followed the setup instructions at
  https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Here's what Python reports:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tc_131.py", line 34, in <module>
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
  File "C:\Users\brent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 814, in set_page_load_timeout
    'pageLoad': int(float(time_to_wait) * 1000)})
  File "C:\Users\brent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 306, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Users\brent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 464, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "C:\Users\brent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 526, in _request
    resp = opener.open(request, timeout=self._timeout)
  File "C:\Users\brent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\brent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Users\brent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\brent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1346, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Users\brent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1321, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\brent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\brent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\brent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 258, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Users\brent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

The simplest test causes the failure:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Ie()

driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
driver.get('https://google.com')
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
```

Comment: Can you share your full test?

Comment: Added the text of a simple test that causes the failure.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem yesterday:

At first I tried to run with 64-bit IEDriverServer.exe version 3.9.0.0 and also had ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054]

And then I download 32-bit IEDriverServer 3.9 from here https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

And my script now is working and IE runs good (even without setting "executable_path" (added to PATH) and time sleeping):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

#driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path="C:\\webdrivers\\IEDriverServer.exe")
driver = webdriver.Ie()
#driver.set_script_timeout(5.0)
#time.sleep(3)

driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
```

Maybe, **you need update version of IEDriverServer** to 3.9
And my python version is higher 3.6.5

Also I **added both register keys** (for 32-bit and 64-bit path) as mentioned in the setup instruction:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration

*I hope this will help...*

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but I am using c# had a read here https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6085 and this solved my problem You might need to read through the discussion

```
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//input[@id='Submit'])[2]")).Click();
```

My understanding is in IE the above syntax is not working but you might want to use this instead

```
    IWebElement submit = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//input[@id='Submit'])[2]"));
        OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions buildersub = new OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions(driver);
        OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions hoverClicksub = buildersub.MoveToElement(submit).MoveByOffset(5, 5).Click();
        hoverClicksub.Build().Perform();
```

Comment: Although the link might solve the problem, please include the essentials of the answer in your actual answer, as the link might become unavailable or experience a content change which would render your answer useless.